# TOAD: Cannot query as it freezes with a current query

Tags: toad

Toad is freezed with the below "cancel pending" status. Can anyone please help me on this as I am not able to execute any query as of now. :(

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It usually happens when you *cancel* a query which takes a lot of time to execute. If it was *updating* something, there's a large undo so yes - it takes time until TOAD cancels the operation.

There are two ways out of it (as far as I know):

- wait until it is done
- *kill* TOAD process (if on MS Windows, use Task Manager to do that) - don't kill the application, but the process

If you saved they query, no problem. Otherwise, TOAD might offer to restore the last session's editor contents. If not, see if F8 (history) returns something. If not, you'll have to write the query from scratch, I'm afraid.

The question is what will the database do; will it rollback? Will it not? I can't tell. From my experience, it just depends. Sometimes the table affected remains locked so you might need the DBA's assistance to kill the database process as well.

Comment: Works always for me. If you do that properly, TOAD will disappear from the desktop, it won't be active any more. You'll have to run it again.

Comment: Yes right. It will close the application. Then once it is opened again, it is directly opening with the page which runs the cancel query.

Comment: Are you sure? Is it not just the query TOAD "saved" for you? There should be checkbox(es) in front of every editor saved which enable you to "Remove" it (if you don't need it). Once you're done, you're allowed to connect to the database again. That's what happens when I do that. Maybe you're right, I can't tell ... if that's so, did you talk to DBA?